# get current category ID php

Tags: php

I'm trying to get category ID of the current archive displayed.

I tried:

```
// category (can be a parent category)
$current_cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
//
print_r ($current_cat_ID);
```

It doesn't print anything...

Comment: where in the template is the code located? are there any custom queries before the code?

Comment: will `cat` always be set regardless of permalink structure, or maybe just `category_name` in some cases? I can't recall at the moment...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

you can use [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object)

```
$category = get_queried_object();
echo $category->term_id;
```

Comment: I've been searching for an answer to his for hours. I wish Wordpress had better documentation. Thank you!

Comment: @Fayaz It will automatically apply to this answer.

Answer (score 4):

A little bit faster than receiving the object and echo the term ID afterwards is to directly use [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/).

Comment: Yeah I agree, strange that no one mentioned this function, they both were available in the same version, wordpress 3.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fecth in category page,you can get id of current category by:

```
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
```

If you want to get category id of any particular category on any page, you can try using below code:

```
$category_id = get_cat_ID('Category Name');
```